# How to pass single element of parameter, declared as array?

Tags: php, symfony

I have in config.yml:

```
parameters:
    aaa:
        bbb: 'Example'
```

If I pass this in service:

```
AppBundle\Service\Service:
    arguments:
        $bbb: '%aaa%'
```

Then this is working well and I have array, but if I pass:

```
AppBundle\Service\Service:
    arguments:
        $bbb: '%aaa.bbb%'
```

Then I have error:

> The service "AppBundle\Service\Service" has a dependency on a non-
>   existent parameter "aaa.bbb". You cannot access nested array
>   items, do you want to inject "aaa" instead?

Is possible to pass only one value?

Comment: BTW, error message answers your question. "You cannot access nested array items".

Comment: may you can check this: https://gist.github.com/tobalsan/ce210d7b2e7dd7c704e7

Comment: You could actually write some code in your extension class and flatten the array into individual parameters.  It's an interesting exercise and something useful to know how to do.  But probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Symfony should have this fixed!

Answer (score 6):

You have to have parameters like this:

```
parameters:
    aaa.bbb: 'Example'
```

with purpose to re-use like:

```
AppBundle\Service\Service:
    arguments:
        $bbb: '%aaa.bbb%'
```

Otherwise, you have to pass whole array, you can't pass single element from array.